# Bifurcation, critical points and parameter dependence in $\nabla_r\,\phi_a(r) = 0$ when varying $a$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix, bifurcation, stationary-point

Suppose I have a function $\phi_a(r)$, where $r \in \mathbb{R}^n$ denotes a real n-dim. vector, and where $a \in \mathbb{R}^p$ denotes a set of additional real parameters.

Suppose that for a given $a$ I have $r_0$, solving

$\nabla_r\,\phi_a(r)|_{r = r_0} = 0$

For fixed $a$ the set of all solutions is denoted by

$E_a[\phi] = \{r: \, \nabla_r\,\phi_a(r) = 0 \}$

I start with the restriction that there are only finitely many solutions in $E_a[\phi]$.

Suppose I start with parameters $a_0$ and change the parameters by an infinitesimal amount

$a_0 \to a = a_0 + \delta a$

In most cases this will change the solutions in $E_{a_0}[\phi]$ by an infinitesimal amount, too (there are counter-examples, e.g. for $\phi_a(r) = |r|^a$ which changes its behaviour at $a = 0, 1$)

So we will have

$r_0 \to r = r_0 + \delta r$

For one solution $\nabla_r\,\phi_a(r)|_{r = r_0} = 0$ varing $a$ defines a curve $C(a)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

$C: \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}^n$

**My questions are:**

What are the *conditions* for the function $\phi$ such that nothing *unexpected* occurs, that by varying $a$ no solution in $E[\phi]$ *disappears*, i.e. that a curve $C(a)$ does not *end* a some point in the parameter space?

What can be said locally, i.e. for infinitesimal changes?

What can be said globally, i.e. for the whole curve?

What is the mathematical discipline dealing with this problem?

Comment: I think that locally this question can be answered by studying the first derivatives plus the Hessian.

Comment: I found out that this should be related to bifurcation theory; from Wikipedia: bifurcation theory is the mathematical study of changes in the qualitative or topological structure of a given family, such as the integral curves (in physics: field lines) of a family of vector fields, and the solutions of a family of differential equations ...